# Can an uncountable set be a "chain"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) about total orders, it's stated that a "chain" is a synonym for a totally ordered set. But this makes no sense to me, since "chain" seems to suggest countability, and yet the real numbers would be a chain because they are totally ordered by "less than or equal to." Am I missing something, or is it true that "chain" can refer to uncountable sets?

Comment: Why does "chain" seem to suggest countability?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I guess that when I picture a chain (http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/seamless-chrome-chain.jpg), I think of the links of the chain as being distinct elements, of which there are only countably many since each link has constant width.

Comment: It's also possible to have an uncountable total order in which each element has an immediate successor and predecessor. (This won't be a subset of $\Bbb R$, though.) I feel like you have a problem with density?

Comment: @justin I see - in that sense, "chain" is a somewhat overloaded word. There is no assumption of discreteness, let alone countability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Chain" can indeed refer to an uncountable set; for instance, $\mathbb{R}$ is a chain in $(\mathbb{R}, <)$.

---

For instance, Zorn's Lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) is usually stated as "If every chain in $\mathbb{P}$ has an upper bound, then $\mathbb{P}$ has a maximal element"; in most interesting cases, most chains in $\mathbb{P}$ are uncountable. For example, when using Zorn's lemma to prove that every set can be well-ordered, the partial order involved is the set of all partial well-orderings of a given set, and this is usually *really* uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can. Consider $\{(-r,r)\mid r\in \Bbb R \text{ and }r>0\}$.